# How to append a a new element in a class using id

Tags: javascript

How to append element in a class using #id post-32

```html
<div id="post-32">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="post-card">
    <a href="#">01</a>
    <div>
      <h3 class="post-title">
        <!-- <h3 class="title">Discover Our </h3> -->new element should here
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var second_post = document.getElementById('post-32');

  var inner_child = second_post.getElementsByTagName('div')[2].childNodes[1];

  var title_scondPost = document.createElement('h3');

  title_scondPost.className = 'title';

  title_scondPost.append(document.createTextNode('Discover Our'));

  inner_child.append(title_scondPost);
</script>
```

Comment: I can't understand what you want.

Comment: What element do you want to append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which is easy to target the element as it allows CSS like selector:

```
document.querySelector('#post-32 > .post-card > div > h3.post-title');
```

```js
var inner_child = document.querySelector('#post-32 > .post-card > div > h3.post-title');
var title_scondPost = document.createElement('h3');
title_scondPost.className = 'title';
title_scondPost.append(document.createTextNode('Discover Our'));
inner_child.append(title_scondPost);
```

```html
<div id="post-32">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="post-card">
    <a href="#">01</a>
    <div>
      <h3 class="post-title">
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: TypeError: Can not read property 'append' of null .this is my problem .the other way  i can append using Jquery  document.ready().

Comment: @KasturiDeepak, if your script is at the bottom of the body then you will not get that error. In vanilla JS, you can wrap your code with `DOMContentLoaded` :)

Answer (score 0):

You already have a h3 tag in the DOM , you don't need t create a new one.

```html
<div id="post-32">

<div></div>

<div></div>

<div class="post-card">

<a href="#">01</a>

<div>

<h3 class="post-title">

<!-- <h3 class="title">Discover Our </h3> --> new element should here

</h3>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<script>

  var second_post = document.getElementById('post-32');

  var inner_child = second_post.getElementsByTagName('div')[2].childNodes[1];

  var title_scondPost = document.getElementsByClassName('post-title')[0];

  title_scondPost.append(document.createTextNode('Discover Our'));

  inner_child.append(title_scondPost);

</script>
```